# Is it possible to install vs2008 after vs2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2008

I have a need to install Visual Studio 2008 for SSRS and SSIS.  I have Visual Studio 2010 and Visual Studio 2015 already installed.  Will I need to uninstall the previous versions and reinstall them in order?

Comment: Consider installing in a virtual machine!

Answer (score 1):

While I would not recommend it (use a VM instead), I recently had to do what you describe. I had an old C++ project that had to be compiled in VS2008, and my existing VS2008 install only had the BIDS portion installed.

It's been about a month, no ill effects for either compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You can install Visual Studio Side-by-Side. You **don't** need to uninstall the previous versions of Visual Studio.

Since you already have Visual Studio 2015 you can install [Download SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt) for VS 2015. With SSDT, you can build Integration Services packages, Analysis Services data models, and Reporting Services reports.

Answer (score 0):

You should uninstall the newer versions first and install them in order.

> We recommend that you install Visual Studio versions in the order in which they were released. For example, install Visual Studio 2013 before you install Visual Studio 2015."
>   <sub>https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246609.aspx</sub>

Comment: Yeah in theory it works in reverse order, but the old installers may install older versions of common libraries or mess up the path environment variables. Safest is to install in order of release or repair later versions after installing older versions. Also don't forget to run Windows update at the end to ensure all patches are re-applied.